# Javascript só funciona se colocado direto na página

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho umas funções e elas só funcionam se colocadas no mesmo arquivo onde está o código que vai usá-las.
Separar com:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/funcoes.js"></script>
```

Funções:

```
$(function($){
    $('#enviar').click(function (e) {
        var linhas = $('#linhas').val();
        var plantas = $('#plantas').val();
        var combo =$('#haoum').val();
        var area = $('#area').val();
        var resultado;
        var resultado2;

        if (combo == "ha") {
            resultado = (Number(area)*Number(10000))/(Number(linhas)*Number(plantas));
            $("#divPrincipal").html('<p class="alert-success">Você terá aproximadamente ' + resultado + ' plantas </p>');
            $("#divsecundaria").html('<p class="alert-success">Com estas configurações você poderá colher em média ' + area*Number(15) + ' toneladas </p>');
        } else {
            resultado = (Number(area))/(Number(linhas)*Number(plantas));
            $("#divPrincipal").html('<p class="alert-success">Você terá aproximadamente ' + resultado + ' plantas </p>');
            $("#secundaria").html('<p class="alert-success">Com estas configurações você poderá colher em média ' + (area/Number(24200))*Number(15) + ' toneladas </p>');
        }
    });
});

$(function($){ 
    $('#enviar2').click(function (e) {
        var linhas = $('#linhas2').val();
        var plantas = $('#plantas2').val();
        var combo = $('#haoum2').val();
        var area = $('#area2').val();
        var resultado;

        if (combo == "ha") {
            resultado=(Number(area))/(Number(linhas)*Number(plantas));
            $("#divPrincipal2").html('<p class="alert-success">Você terá aproximadamente ' + resultado + ' plantas </p>');
        } else {
            resultado = (Number(area)/Number(10000))/(Number(linhas)*Number(plantas));
            $("#divPrincipal2").html('<p class="alert-success">Você terá aproximadamente ' + resultado + ' plantas </p>');
        }    
    });
 });
```

Alguém sabe onde está errado?

Comment: Nao tem nescessidade de 2 `$(function($){`. Voce pode colocar tudo dentro de 1, lembrando que esta usando jquery, portanto você deve incluir a biblioteca jquery antes desse arquivo com as funcoes

Comment: E a causa do problema é exatamente o que o @AntonyAlkmim disse: o que está dentro de um `$(function($){` não enxerga o que tem no outro. São escopos distintos.

Comment: Além disso, verifique o Inspetor de Rede e assegure-se de que esse arquivo, nesse diretório está sendo encontrado no âmbito da Requisição que precisa dele.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você está com problema provavelmente na hora de colocar o seu arquivo na página, verifique se o jQuery foi linkado na página antes do seu código.

Para facilitar também, em vez de criar dois escopos  de:

```
$(function($){ });
```

Você poderia colocar os seus .click() dentro de um document ready:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#seletor1').click(function(){
       ...
    });
    $('#seletor2').click(function(){
       ...
    });
});
```

além de você garantir que os eventos seja atrelados aos elementos após o carregamento da página, o código fica mais legível